# Bad wkhtmltopdf's path - wicked_pdf on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I downloaded whkhtmltopdf manually via:

```
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
```

After this I changed my wicked_pdf.rb to:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #:layout => "pdf.html",
  :exe_path => 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

I tried "where wkhtmltopdf" in my windows console and I obtain this:

```
c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin\wkhtmltopdf
c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin\wkhtmltopdf.bat
```

After change change "exe_path" I obtain the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
:exe_path => 'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
```

Comment: New error:

`["C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe", "file://C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/wicked_pdf20151007-2572-3ytogu.html", "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20151007-2572-93hmvr.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
Command Error: Loading pages (1/6)

Error: Failed loading page file://c/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/wicked_pdf20151007-864-1qs3w7v.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you must specify the exe extension.

so the current configuration is

```
WickedPdf.config = {   :exe_path => 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' }
```